# Ridge regression gives me this plot. How to interpret it?

Tags: logistic, ridge-regression

I have done this plot with cv.glmnet(), can someone help me to interpret it?

[image]

I also noticed that I get 2 different lambdas: lambda.min and lambda.1se

What is the difference between these lambdas?
Why the graph is so thick than normal?
What can I understand from the above plot in general (what are these confidence intervals about, what are the two dotted lines etc)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See Page 5 of the [`glmnet` vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/vignettes/glmnet.pdf) for explanation of the two lambdas and this type of graph. Most examples there are for mean-squared error as a model-quality estimate, but the same principles apply to deviance. The apparent thickness of the graph is due to the y-axis scale; the upper and lower limits are only 0.025 units apart, around estimates on the order of 0.75 units. If you set the y-axis minimum to 0 this would look much narrower.

Comment: The duplicate was found by searching our site for your title.  For more like it, see [the remaining hits](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cv.glmnet+plot).